# How to refresh the datatable inline editor after getting data from service?

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I have added inline editing data features for my datatable.  I'm using service call to get the latest data and I'm binding to the datatable using dtOptions. I'm using datatable " ". intially empty data variable binding. as soon as i get data from service i'm binding to the dtOptions which is binding(showing) well. but inline editing is not working. I'm not sure how to add data to editor after getting from service. if i add accessing instance of  $.fn.dataTable.Editor. it's just not working. please help to solve this issue.

**HTML**

`<table id='dtGrid'  *ngIf="dtRendered" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>`

**script**

```
 data = [];

renderDatatable(dtColumns, modelObjAttributes) {
    console.log('dtEditor', this.dtEditor);
    const colLenth = dtColumns.length;
    this.dtRendered = false;
    this.dtOptions = {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',      
        data: this.data,
        pageLength: 100,
        columns: dtColumns,
        columnDefs: [ {
          targets: colLenth,
          defaultContent: '',
          title: '<i class="fa fa-plus plusIcon"></i>',
          orderable: false
        }],
        paging: true,
        searching: true,
      //  ordering: true,
        info:     false,
        responsive: true,
        drawCallback: () => {
          const btnElement = this.dtTableId.nativeElement.querySelector('i.plusIcon');
          this.renderer.listen(btnElement, 'click', ($event) => {
              this.onClickPlusIcon(modelObjAttributes);
           });
        },
        scrollY: '500px',
      //  bSort: false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        select: {
          style:    'os',
          selector: 'td:first-child'
         },
        buttons: [
          { extend: 'create', editor: this.dtEditor },
          { extend: 'edit',   editor: this.dtEditor },
          { extend: 'remove', editor: this.dtEditor }
          // { extend:  'pageLength', editor: this.dtEditor}
        ]
      };
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.dtRendered = true;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.attachPlusIconClickEvent(modelObjAttributes);
    this.attachDtClickEvent();
}

// This method used to initialize the data table dyanamically
initializeDtEditor(dtColumns, modelObjAttributes) {
    this.dtEditor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({  
    data: this.data,
    table: '#dtGrid',
    idSrc: this.uniqueField,
    fields: this.dataTableFields,
    formOptions: {
      inline: {
        onBackground:  'blur',
        onBlur:        'close',
        onComplete:    'close',
        onEsc:         'close',
        onFieldError:  'focus',
        onReturn:      'submit',
        submit:        'changed',
        scope:         'row'
      }
    }
   });
   // this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.renderDatatable(dtColumns, modelObjAttributes);
}


// This method to get the data from service if you see i'm binding the reponseData to dtOptions. It adding to the datatable but it's not allowing to edit(inline edit). with buttong edit it's working.

getData(modelName) {
  this.dtServiceService.readData(modelName).subscribe(responseData => {
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));   
   this.dtOptions['data'] = responseData;
   this.dtRendered = false;
   this.cdr.detectChanges();
   this.dtRendered = true;
   this.cdr.detectChanges();

  },
  error => {
    console.log('data is not getting!');
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance of your issue?

Comment: @Prince - I have added in stackblitiz though it's not working but if you see my code you will get that what i'm asking. I'm reinitializing after getting data also. here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-replace-all-the-columns-dynamically-in-data-table-vgykyp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Prince - because of re-initializing datatable is flickering.

Comment: @bagya That stackblitz doesn't compile. Can you get to at least compile?

Comment: @KurtHamilton - Please check it now

Comment: @bagya I would request you to make a working instance with dummy data atleast.

Comment: Downvoting since this question does not meat the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) criteria. Nobody would be able to answer it. There is also no actual code which reproduces the issue and we are no mind readers to be able to answer this. Also, your `stackblitz` example uses `ViewChild` chihd references to non-existing elements - `@ViewChild('dtGrid')` would search for an element in the template which like `<table #dtGrid...`, but in your example it only has an `id` attribute <table id='dtGrid'...`.

Comment: @tftd - I will reproduce the issue using stackblitz and then will update you.

Answer (score 2):

**[Angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)** provides a **dtTrigger** you can use to manually **trigger** the rendering of the table.

What you need to do is calling the **`dtTrigger`** to manually render the table.

Example :

**HTML :**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
    <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Typescript :**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Person } from '../person';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-angular-way',
  templateUrl: 'angular-way.component.html'
})
export class AngularWayComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  persons: Person[] = [];
  // We use this trigger because fetching the list of persons can be quite long,
  // thus we ensure the data is fetched before rendering
  dtTrigger: Subject = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 2
    };
    this.http.get('data/data.json')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .subscribe(persons => {
        this.persons = persons;
        // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
  }
}
```